# React Native firebase OTP only works with test numbers and not with my real number

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

I followed this guide: https://rnfirebase.io/auth/phone-auth to add OTP to my app but it only works with the test numbers i set up at the firebase console website and does nothing when i enter my real number. Code below:

```
function Phone() {
  // If null, no SMS has been sent
  const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState(null);
  const [code, setCode] = useState('');

  // Handle the button press
  async function signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
    const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    setConfirm(confirmation);
  }

  async function confirmCode() {
    try {
      await confirm.confirm(code);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Invalid code.');
    }
  }

  //+20 123 456 9879

  if (!confirm) {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <Button
            title="Phone Number Sign In"
            onPress={() => signInWithPhoneNumber('//My real number')}
          />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <TextInput value={code} onChangeText={text => setCode(text)} />
      <Button title="Confirm Code" onPress={() => confirmCode()} />
    </>
  );
}

export default Phone;
```

Answer (score 0):

To work with real numbers you should be running the project in real device else it won't.
In emulator only test numbers work.